# Calculo de Frete Ajax e Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou desenvolvendo uma loja virtual onde no carrinho de compras irei implementar o calculo de frete via webservice dos correios.

O codigo abaixo ele faz o calculo e retorna somente a opção de Pac, preciso que conforme o usuario selecione a opção sedex ele faça o calculo e me mostre o valor referente ao sedex. Nao estou conseguindo implementar o select, está aparecendo que a var tipo_frete não está definida.

```
function LoadFrete() {

var cep_destino = $('#cep_destino').val();
//var tipo_frete = $('tipo_frete').val();



$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/a_frete.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    cache: false,
    data: {cep_destino: cep_destino},
    success: function (data) {

        console.log('Valor = ' + data);

        $('#valor_frete').val(data);

        var val_prod = $('#valor_pro').val();

        val_prod = val_prod.replace(',', '.');
        data     = data.replace(',', '.');

        var total = parseFloat(data) + parseFloat(val_prod);

        $('#valor_prodfrete').val(total);



    }, beforeSend: function () {

    }, error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('Erro');

    }
});
}
```

Comment: Está indefinida por que a `var tipo_frete` está comentada, tira o `//`

Comment: tipo_frete é class ou id ?

Comment: Bom dia Mateus e Advenstistaam, mesmo tirando // ela permanece indefinida. tipo_frete é uma variavel na função do webservice dos correios. $url .= "&nCdServico=04510,04014" .$tipo_frete; - $dados = calcula_frete('14802175', $cep_destino, 5, 1, $tipo_frete); -

Comment: mas ai você está chamando do seu formulario

Answer (score 1):

Depende do que você está utilizando no seu form, se é class ou id

Exemplo:

```js
$('.btn-calcular').on('click', function(){
   var tipo_frete_class = $('.tipo_frete').val();
   var tipo_frete_id = $('#tipo_frete').val();
   
   alert("Tipo Frete  class: "+tipo_frete_class+
        "\nTipo de Frete id: "+tipo_frete_id);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<label for="tipo_frete">Tipo Frete Class</label>
<div class="col-lg-4">
<select class="form-control tipo_frete col-lg-2" >
  <option value="1">Normal</option>
  <option value="2">Sedex</option>
</select>

<br><br>

<label for="tipo_frete">Tipo Frete ID</label>
<select class="form-control  col-lg-2" id="tipo_frete">
  <option value="1">Normal</option>
  <option value="2">Sedex</option>
</select>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-calcular">Calcular</button>
```

E no dataType, tente usar json

```
dataType: 'json'
```

Comment: Muito boa noite Adventistaam me perdoe a demora em responder, mas continua dando variavel indefinida na linha 4 do arquivo ajax/a_frete.php,  https://pastebin.com/QhDW8L43

Comment: Consegui declarar a variavel tipo_frete faltava declarar ela no data no arquivo frete.js

Comment: mas nao estou conseguindo implementar o select

Comment: A partir daí, você pode fazer sua consulta, pode usar o $.ajax({ })